# Issues with React Terminal when installing react router. Windows

Tags: npm, npm-audit

I'm having multiple issues with my React terminal when trying to install different things.
I'm mainly having this issue with installing react router and linking my projects to Github.

*The issue seems to be the 'high severity vulnerabilities' as this is common when I try to do anything within the terminal

I'm new to React and this is slowing my progress. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Here's what is returned in my Terminal:

Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\Lenovo\test-app> npm install react-router-dom@5
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

added 10 packages, changed 3 packages, and audited 1473 packages in 12s

208 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\test-app>

Comment: These are warnings, not errors, so they should ***not*** be blocking anything. Did you follow any of the suggestions from the warning?

Comment: Yes, I tried npm audit fix --force but didn't seem to work

Comment: What command are you running? Just trying to install the latest v5 version of `react-router-dom`? What are the vulnerabilities listed? Which packages need to be updated?

Comment: I've tried 'npm install react-router-dom@6' and @5.

Comment: trying to get the rest now

Comment: These are *just* warnings and in my experience it's not uncommon to have a few when installing dependencies. Just review them via `npm audit` and if, in *your* opinion, any of them seem like they'd directly affect the security of your app then dig in on those to see what exactly needs to be updated. `npm audit fix` isn't a silver bullet, and you don't necessarily want to run it with the `--force` flag as this will bump major versions that may include breaking changes to the code you are using.

Comment: th-check  <2.0.1 
Severity: high    
Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rp65-9cf3-cjxr
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@2.1.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/svgo/node_modules/nth-check
  css-select  <=3.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of nth-check
  node_modules/svgo/node_modules/css-select
    svgo  1.0.0 - 1.3.2

Comment: Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
    node_modules/svgo
      @svgr/plugin-svgo  <=5.5.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo
        @svgr/webpack  4.0.0 - 5.5.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/plugin-svgo
        node_modules/@svgr/webpack
          react-scripts  >=2.1.4
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
          node_modules/react-scripts

6 high severity vulnerabilities

Comment: I cant attach the whole message but ive sent it in 2 seperate parts. Hopefully it doesnt look too messy!